# how to find the right value of MTU Jumbo frame

Tags: network, linux, mtu, performance

we take the decision to set jumbo frame on all our linux machines

we have hadoop cluster with master machines , workers machines and kafka machines

our switches ( Cisco ) are suitable to Jumbo frame and that fine

but jumbo frame can set as 8000 or 9000 or between them or less then 8000 what is the formula to calculate what is the best MTU value ?

Comment: Removed the off-topic question about host configuration.

Comment: "_our switches ( Cisco ) are suitable to Jumbo frame and that fine_" Some Cisco switches have different jumbo frame sizes for different interfaces. You need to make sure that all the devices in a path have all the possible interfaces in a path set to the same size.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure there's a notable performance difference between jumbos and standard frames - without it, there's little reason to dive in. Hardware offloading tends to make jumbos obsolete unless you need the final 4% throughput.
2. You should consider your latency and QoS requirements. Jumbos increase latency and may hurt QoS.
3. Check your equipment for the jumbo size where it's still reliable. Several devices support jumbos but behave rather poorly with them. Buffers may be too small.

The configuration of the hosts is off-topic here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, I have set-up 9000 or 9216 (Maximum). It depend on your NIC and another devices which direct connect with the switch.